# play MIDI files in python?

Tags: python, midi

I'm looking for a method to play midi files in python.
It seems python does not support MIDI in its standard library.
After I searched, I found some python midi librarys such as [pythonmidi](http://www.mxm.dk/products/public/pythonmidi/). 
However, most of them can only create and read MIDI file without playing function.
I would like to find a python midi library including playing method.
Any recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: Playing them how? Through a MIDI port? Through a software synthesiser?

Comment: I'd like to write a python player that can both play midi and process midi file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pygame module can be used to play midi files.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html

See the example here:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216979

a whole bunch of options available at:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

and also here which you can modify to suit your purpose:
http://xenon.stanford.edu/~geksiong/code/playmus/playmus.py

Answer (score 10):

Just to add a minimal example (via [DaniWeb](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216979/embed-and-play-midi-music-in-your-code-python)):

```
# conda install -c cogsci pygame
import pygame

def play_music(midi_filename):
  '''Stream music_file in a blocking manner'''
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()
  pygame.mixer.music.load(midi_filename)
  pygame.mixer.music.play()
  while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    clock.tick(30) # check if playback has finished
    
midi_filename = 'FishPolka.mid'

# mixer config
freq = 44100  # audio CD quality
bitsize = -16   # unsigned 16 bit
channels = 2  # 1 is mono, 2 is stereo
buffer = 1024   # number of samples
pygame.mixer.init(freq, bitsize, channels, buffer)

# optional volume 0 to 1.0
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.8)

# listen for interruptions
try:
  # use the midi file you just saved
  play_music(midi_filename)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  # if user hits Ctrl/C then exit
  # (works only in console mode)
  pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(1000)
  pygame.mixer.music.stop()
  raise SystemExit
```

Comment: Super useful.  Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 8):

[pretty_midi](https://github.com/craffel/pretty-midi) can generate the waveform for you, you can then play it with e.g. `IPython.display.Audio`

```py
from IPython.display import Audio
from pretty_midi import PrettyMIDI

sf2_path = 'path/to/sf2'  # path to sound font file
midi_file = 'music.mid'

music = PrettyMIDI(midi_file=midi_file)
waveform = music.fluidsynth(sf2_path=sf2_path)
Audio(waveform, rate=44100)
```

Comment: Seems a better (lighter) solution than the remotely related pygame. A [show case from two well know authors](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/C1/C1S2_MIDI.html) in music analysis and DSP.

Comment: This is ~not~ lighter weight than pygame. You need to install a separate fluid synth application, and then python bindings for that application.

Answer (score 4):

Use pygame to play your midi file. Examples are [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html) or [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216976)

Answer (score 2):

I find that [midi2audio](https://pypi.org/project/midi2audio/) works well.

Example:

```
from midi2audio import FluidSynth

#Play MIDI

FluidSynth().play_midi('input.mid')

#Synthesize MIDI to audio

# Note: the default sound font is in 44100 Hz sample rate

fs = FluidSynth()
fs.midi_to_audio('input.mid', 'output.wav')

# FLAC, a lossless codec, is recommended

fs.midi_to_audio('input.mid', 'output.flac')
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can use the pyObjC library to access the OS's own MIDI handling routines. This script will play midi files given as arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from AVFoundation import AVMIDIPlayer
from Foundation import NSURL
import time
import sys

def myCompletionHandler():
    return

def playMIDIFile(filepath):
    midiFile = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filepath)
    midiPlayer, error = AVMIDIPlayer.alloc().initWithContentsOfURL_soundBankURL_error_(midiFile, None, None)
    if error:
        print (error)
        sys.exit(1)
    MIDItime = midiPlayer.duration()
    midiPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    midiPlayer.play_(myCompletionHandler)
    if not midiPlayer.isPlaying:
        midiPlayer.stop()
    else:
        time.sleep(MIDItime)
    return  
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        playMIDIFile(filename)
```