# How to play musical notes in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote some code in Python which randomly picks numbers and converts them into music notes in a text file. But I want to know if there is a way to play the notes and music. If there is a package, are there tutorials or docs that I could look into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Making music is a pretty broad subject.
I think the closest thing to what you ask for is midi. A pretty simple protocol where you can tell what note to play for how long. These questions should help you along with how to [write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11059801/383793) midi files and then [play](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6030087/383793) them.

If you actually want to create the waves yourself and synthesise the sound [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33880295/383793) should help.

But the subject is broad and there's a long (non exhaustive) list of [music software written in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic).